# How to automatically import newly created contact from Salesforce to MarketingCloud/ExactTarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

We worked with a SFMC parter that set up the connector, integrated SFMC to Shopify, and set up a Salesforce Synchronized Data Extension (not sendable). The synchronized DE contact count increases when a new contact is created, however a new contact/subscriber is not created. Though a new contact is created in SFMC when a new Shopify account is created.

My question is, how can I automatically have a new contact/subscriber created when a contact is created in Salesforce Cloud?

I am able to export new contact from Salesforce Cloud and import the contacts into a DE in SFMC, but I'd like to find a more efficient way.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why do you need them created in the all subs list ? :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'easy' option here.
Option one is using automation studio. Here you need data extract, file transfer, import subscriber. 
Option two is using custom integration (read: Apex and SOAP API) to update all subscribers when there is a data change in SFDC.

Comment: The new import method is new - but works wonders :)

Comment: I can only see All Contacts - Push and All Contacts - Mobile, is there another we can add via Support? I haven't managed to find any documentation on it?

Comment: You need to create an import using contact builder - are you doing it from there?

Comment: Yep, Contact -> Import -> List -> (only push and sms here), got a screenshot?

Comment: Hmmm.. I am sure i saw it pre june release, but i can't seem to find that list either. The alternative might be to reach out to support, to ask them - or import the contacts to a population DE, if that fits the use case. But strange.. will continue to pursue this one for clarification.

Comment: :D I'll leave you to reach out then, last I was told it doesnt exist. I have an idea in Success, where someone from SF commented so if it is there, she doesnt seem to be aware. 
Populations are fine for having them added to All Subs on send time, but it wont pull in attributes :/

Comment: Haha Awesome ! Will come back If i hear anything :-D

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods for doing this based on your outline:

1. Send a confirmation email to the newly created record, but do it through SFMC - and make sure you have the right Id (the easiest here would be doing a Journey based on when records are created meeting certain criteria). This would automatically create them in all subscribers (use all sub's in your email config)
2. You can use automation studio to achieve the same.

   - Step 1: Create SQL to populate data extension:
   - Step 2: Create import definition to all subscribers (you can only do this via Contact Builder, under imports) (this is pending verification, following june release, you might need to drop file as per doug's answer)
   - Step 3: Go into automation studio and drop the two activities onto the steps
   - Step 4: schedule it